# Use web-services instead of a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I want to build an ASP.NET MVC3 application but instead of a model I would like to use a web-service. (WVC -Web-service - Views - Controller instead of the traditional MVC3, Model - View - Controller).

The reason behind this selection is the need to use the same database for a Windows Phone Application and a Website.

Which is the most "proper", "correct" way to use webservices in my application? Is it better to call them from the Controller? Or use them from the Model?

I am new in Asp.Net MVC3 and I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: On a side note: Microsoft states that you should use async over sync using a webservice whenever you can. So also take a look at AsyncController if it is right in your situation.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC4/C# 5 add much richer support of asyc via Task and Task<t>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what you mean, however my take on your question would be as follows:

If your web service is serving up xml or JSON you would consume the service & deserialize related data at the controller level. In the event you need to present information to a user you would populate a model / view model from the previously deserialized data and render a view.

In the event data needs to be passed back to the service the data would flow from the view into the controller to be serialized and sent back to your webservice.